# Alternative to Task queue on Google Cloud Kubernetes

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform

I found out that the task queue is being primarily used for App Engine standard environment. I am migrating our existing services from App Engine to Kubernetes. What would be a good alternative for task queue? Push queue is the one which is being currently used.

I read documentation online as well as gone through this link: [When to use PubSub vs Task Queues](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/IcIjLfgnNXs)
But there is no clear answer as to whether Pub/Sub is a good alternative on Kubernetes.

Edit:

My current use case is that a service performs similar tasks for a set of ID's and some task which takes some time to complete so the queue would take this task and process it while the service can perform other things in parallel. While Pub/Sub is mainly needed where we have publisher and subscriber here the service itself has some tasks which it needs to keep processing in parallel!

Answer (score 0):

I would think [Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/) is a great tool for message queues. It's orthogonal to how you deploy/run your services, whether with Kubernetes or something else.

There's a lot of relevant documentation for using pubsub with Kubernetes on GCP, like [this page](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/connect-to-cloud-pubsub-via-service-broker).

Comment: My current use case is that a service performs similar tasks for a set of ID's and some task which takes some time to complete so the queue would take this task and process it while the service can perform other things parallely. While pubsub is mainly needed where we have publisher and subscriber here the service itself has some tasks which it needs to keep processing parallely!

Comment: @BatmanRises: is that in the same process or are the tasks processed in a separate process?

Comment: Indeed Eli, but Cloud Pub/Sub does not allow deferred execution based on an ETA