# GKE and Task Queues

Tags: kubernetes, queue, task, gpu, google-kubernetes-engine

I am working on a cloud service platform that consists of getting tasks from users, executing them, and giving back the results.

**TL;DR**
Is there a way to have a "task queue", where tasks can be inserted via a REST API, and extracted automatically by the Google Kubernetes Engine cluster by guaranteeing an automatic scaling?

**Long description**
Users can send tasks in parallel, and each task is time consuming and need to be performed on a GPU. So, setting up an auto-scaling GPU cluster is what I thought of.
More in particular, in my idea, users could send tasks/data through a REST API, the REST API provides in filling a task queue, and the task queue itself will feed tasks to workers on the GPU auto-scaling cluster. Of course, there are other details (authentication, database, storage, etc.) that have to be addressed but are not the point of my question.

For reasons I don't specify here, the project is already started on the Google Cloud Platform, so switching to AWS or other providers is not an option.

For what I understood, things seem a bit different from standard Docker-only clusters in AWS, that is, we have to use the Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) to setup the auto-scaling cluster, even for "simple" GPU-enabled Docker containers.

By looking at the not-so-exhaustive documentation, I know that queues are used, but what I don't know is whether feeding of tasks to the cluster is automatically handled. Also, the so-called "Task Queue" service has been deprecated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a quick chat with batch developers, the current solution (before the batch service become public) is to adopt a third-party queue system like [Slurm](https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm-gcp).

Answer (score 0):

First I thought [Cloud Tasks queues](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/) may be the answer to your troubles, but more this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54679926/alternative-to-task-queue-on-google-cloud-kubernetes) seems to promote  [Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/) as a better alternative.

Comment: I think the pub/sub alternative does not take into account the queue mechanism.